# I am trying to validate my email in react I am able to validate the email if typed but my email verification fails if email is pasted

Tags: reactjs, react-native

This is the form field for email:

```
<Form.Group>
  <label className="field-lbl">Email</label>
  <Form.Control
  type="email"
  className="form-control"
  name="email"
  value={email}
  onChange={this.handleEmailChange}
  autoComplete="off"
  ></Form.Control>
  {showError && !this.state.email.trim().length ? (
  <div className="help-block">email is required</div>
  ) : invalemail ? (
  <div className="help-block">Invalid email</div>
  ) : (
  <div></div>
  )}
 </Form.Group>
```

This is an on change event for my input in form:

```
handleEmailChange = (event) => {
    const email = event.target.value;
    console.log(email);
    if (email.length === 0) {
      this.setState({ showError: true });
    } else {
      const emailValidators =
        /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
      this.setState({
        emailValidate: emailValidators.test(String(email).toLowerCase()),
      });
      if (this.state.emailValidate === false) {
        this.setState({ invalemail: true, showError: true });
      } else {
        this.setState({ invalemail: false, showError: false });
      }
    }
    this.setState({ email });
  };
```

I am able to verify the email if entered but my email verification fails if the email is copy-pasted (though if you modify even a single character after pasting it works).

Answer (score 1):

I had to add an onBlur event so as to access the email verification even when the email was copy-pasted (only problem now is that, I need to click outside the field to remove the error.)

updated form:

```
<Form.Group>
                        <label className="field-lbl">Email</label>
                        <Form.Control
                          type="email"
                          className="form-control"
                          name="email"
                          value={email}
                          onChange={this.handleEmailChange}
                          onBlur={this.handleEmailblur}
                          autoComplete="off"
                        ></Form.Control>
                        {showError && !this.state.email.trim().length ? (
                          <div className="help-block">email is required</div>
                        ) : invalemail ? (
                          <div className="help-block">Invalid email</div>
                        ) : (
                          <div></div>
                        )}
                      </Form.Group>
```

onBlur handler:

```
handleEmailblur = () => {
    const email = this.state.email;
    const emailValidators =
      /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    this.setState({
      emailValidate: emailValidators.test(String(email).toLowerCase()),
    });

    if (this.state.emailValidate) {
      this.setState({ invalemail: false, showError: false });
    } else {
      this.setState({ invalemail: true, showError: true });
    }
  };
```

onChange handler

```
handleEmailChange = (event) => {
    const email = event.target.value.trim();
    if (email.length === 0) {
      this.setState({ showError: true });
    } else {
      const emailValidators =
        /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
      this.setState({
        emailValidate: emailValidators.test(String(email).toLowerCase()),
        // emailValidate: emailValidators.test(email.toLowerCase()),
      });
      if (this.state.emailValidate === false) {
        this.setState({ invalemail: true, showError: true });
      } else {
        this.setState({ invalemail: false, showError: false });
      }
    }
    this.setState({ email });
  };
```